# Shell.namespace not accepting string variable, but accepting string itself

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code, in which I want to loop through files in a folder, check their built-in or custom document properties (without opening them), and later open those, which are meant to be open.
To do this, I'm using `Shell` and to set the folder I'm using `Shell.Namespace`.

**The problem** is with the `Namespace`, I guess. When I use a *variable* `strSuborCesta` for the path  *it doesn't work*. When I print the variable `strSuborCesta` into immediate window and use the printed *string* inside the `Shell.Namespace("....")` *it does work*.

By *it doesn't work* I mean I get:

> run-time error : 91 Object variable or With block not set

when I try to loop through the files in folder (which is not set in that case, so I understand why the error occurred, but don't understand why it's not accepting a string variable)

The path is correct in both ways. But **I need it to be a variable**, not a hardcoded string.

**Where do I error?**

**Is there any better way, to check document properties (like comments, title, author, etc.) without opening the Excel files?**

Below is the section (currently just in testing phase) that is giving me a hard time.

`str[name of variable]` variables are string data types. `sFile, oShell, oDir are as Variants`

```
 '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'get a root path
strPriecinokCesta = ThisWorkbook.Path 'path to this file
strPriecinokCesta = Left(strPriecinokCesta, Len(strPriecinokCesta) - (Len(strPriecinokCesta) - InStrRev(strPriecinokCesta, "\"))) 'root path is one level above this file
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'input files are in a subfolder
strSuborCesta = strPriecinokCesta & "Zdroje\"
strSuborPripona = "Formular_BD_kotolna*.xls" 'name of a file with extension
strSuborNazov = Dir(strSuborCesta & strSuborPripona) 'actual file name
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'get access to the file system
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set oDir = oShell.Namespace(strSuborCesta) '<----this will produce an error. In contrast to using a hard coded string. Why?

For Each sFile In oDir.Items '<---- run time error 91 occurs on this line
    Debug.Print test & " : " & oDir.GetDetailsOf(sFile, 24) 'comments
Next
```

Comment: Does `strSuborNazov` actually contain the _full path_ to the file?

Comment: Sorry, I had an error there, used different variable with a file name `strSuborNazov `. The correct one should be `strPriecinokCesta` that is the folder path. Edited. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: To my previous comment...`strSuborCesta` is the correct variable, that should be used. That is the folder, with input files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable strSuborNazov should be a variant

```
Dim strSuborNazov as variant 

oShell.Namespace(strSuborNazov)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774085(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This made no difference for me

Answer (score 0):

High

Had this prob as well, with something like this

```
 Set objWSOFolder = objWSO.Namespace(Parf)
```

Saw this https://microsoft.public.access.narkive.com/Jl55mts5/problem-using-shell-namespace-method-in-vba#post5 so tried

```
Set objWSOFolder = objWSO.Namespace((Parf))
```

That worked.

I noticed later, that I did not have the problem if at least part of the path was given as a literal string. So I tried something like this

```
Set objWSOFolder = objWSO.Namespace("" & Parf)
```

That worked too. Whoopy Hoo, 4 me & U

Alan