# Word VBA: Insert a picture without known aspect ratio of file

Tags: vba, ms-word

.addPicture requires width and height, but this could end up distorting the image. Is there any way to use .LockAspectRatio = msoCTrue when adding the file image?

Also, how do you stipulate a page to put the canvas or the picture? Macro recorder needs to be stopped before one can work on images somehow.

```
Set sCanvas = ActiveDocument.Shapes _
 .AddCanvas(Left:=MillimetersToPoints(20), Top:=MillimetersToPoints(20), _
 Width:=300, Height:=200)
Set CanvasShapes = sCanvas.CanvasItems

 With CanvasShapes
 .AddPicture FileName:="C:\somepath\image.png", _
 Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=150, Height:=100
  ...
 End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to obtain the dimensions using the code [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5f375529-a002-4312-a54b-b70d6d3eb6ae/how-to-retrieve-image-dimensions-using-vba-?forum=accessdev) (pasted below for reference)

```
Sub test()

Dim objShell As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim fPath As Variant 'MUST be a variant, not a string
Dim fName As String

fPath = "C:\somepath"
fName = "image.png"

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(fPath)
Set objFile = objFolder.ParseName(fName)

MsgBox objFile.ExtendedProperty("Dimensions")

End Sub
```

This will give you the dimensions of the picture which you can then use.

It looks like the output is `? w x h ?` so you'll need to parse it, but this should work.

Note that if you want to use a variable to define the file path, it must be declared as a variant, per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33868233/shell-namespace-not-accepting-string-variable-but-accepting-string-itself/33868523)

Comment: I tried to have a string variable in the set objFile line like "=objFolder.ParseNase(fName), but got an object variable not set error. Not found a way to overcome that. Can I only have an actual string inside and not a string variable?

Comment: See edit.  The problem is actually in the line above that when you are setting the folder.  `fPath` must be declared as a variant, per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33868233/shell-namespace-not-accepting-string-variable-but-accepting-string-itself/33868523

Comment: Thank you so much @opiesdad.

Answer (score 2):

Set the canvas size to 0 and lock it's aspect ratio, *then* add the picture.  The canvas will scale to accommodate it.  After the image is loaded, *then* scale the canvas as needed:

```
Set sCanvas = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddCanvas(MillimetersToPoints(20), MillimetersToPoints(20), 0, 0)
sCanvas.LockAspectRatio = True
Set CanvasShapes = sCanvas.CanvasItems

With CanvasShapes
   .AddPicture "C:\somepath\image.png"
End With

'Scale the canvas here.
```

Comment: Thanks @Comintern. So I would then just shaperange.scalewidth and scaleheight to change canvas size afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

If you check the definition of the AddPicture method you will find that except for FileName all of the arguments are optional, so Height and Width are not required.

Unless you have a specific reason for adding a canvas it is also unnecessary to add a canvas before adding a picture.

Word has no concept of pages so you cannot specify that the picture should appear on a certain page.

Comment: Thanks @m4o_tim, yes, discovered the optional nature of the other arguments from play with it. I was unsure about canvas since Word does not permit recoreding macros when it involves shapes and images.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find a way to put a picture to a specific page (page 2 in example below) in MS Word:

```
Dim pNum as long
pNum = 2
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Count:= pNum
```