# Modify a Windows Shortcut Path using VBA with MS Access 2016

Tags: vba, ms-access

Trying to create a simple routine to modify a shortcut target path. I found an outdated shell reference that I was hoping to tweak.

It's assumed that the shortcut lives on the user's desktop. The plan is to call it like this `ChangeShortcut "Test.lnk", "C:/users/environ$("username") & "/" & OneDrive-Personal/DBFolder/PMD_FE.accdb"`

The following routine gets stuck at `objfolder.ParseName(strNameOfShortCut)` here is the complete routine:

```
Public Sub ChangeShortcut(strNameOfShortCut As String, strNewShortcutTarget As String)

    Const ALL_USERS_DESKTOP = &H19&

    Dim objShell As Object 'shell As Shell32.shell
    Dim objfolder As Object 'Shell32.folder
    Dim objfolderItem As Object 'Shell32.folderItem
    Dim objShortcut As Object 'Shell32.ShellLinkObject
    Dim objShellLink As Object
     
   
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
   
    Set objfolder = objShell.Namespace(ALL_USERS_DESKTOP)
    If Not objfolder Is Nothing Then
        Set objfolderItem = objfolder.ParseName(strNameOfShortCut)
        If Not objfolderItem Is Nothing Then
            Set objShortcut = objfolderItem.GetLink
            If Not objShortcut Is Nothing Then
                objShortcut.Path = strNewShortcutTarget    'To Change
                objShortcut.Save
                MsgBox "Shortcut changed"
            Else
                MsgBox "Shortcut link within file not found"
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Shortcut file not found"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Desktop folder not found"
    End If
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Make `strNameOfShortCut` a Variant, not a String. The Shell object sometimes has problems with String parameters.  Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33868233/shell-namespace-not-accepting-string-variable-but-accepting-string-itself

Comment: FYI "gets stuck" is not a very useful description of the exact problem you're having when running your code:  if you get an error it's useful to include the error message in your post.

Comment: I changed strNameOfShortCut to variant.  I hear what you mean by "gets stuck" not being very descriptive, only it doesn't throw an error.  The line 'If Not objfolderItem Is Nothing' is false, so the msgbox says 'Shortcut file not found' - but 'Test.lnk' does, in fact exist on the desktop.

Comment: Maybe change `strNewShortcutTarget` to Variant also - sorry I didn't catch that earlier.

Comment: And your call should be more like this: `ChangeShortcut "Test.lnk", "C:/users/" & environ$("username") & "/OneDrive-Personal/DBFolder/PMD_FE.accdb"`   You can't embed the literal string `environ$("username")` in the path.

Comment: That is correct.  This is my actual call  ChangeShortcut "Test.lnk", LocalWorkingPath & "\PMD_FE" & ".accdb"  
I apologize for not formatting these inline comments as code.  I don't know how to do them in comments.  (LocalWorkingPath is as you have specified).  Still no change.

Comment: This may be a permissions problem - I can't get this to work in the "all users" desktop either, but it works fine on my personal desktop.

Comment: Can I substitute this for ALL_USERS_DESKTOP:  strDesktop = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")  which currently works for copying the shortcut on the server to my desktop?

Comment: Where is the link you're trying to edit?  On the "public" (all users) desktop, or on your own desktop ?

Comment: A master shortcut exists on the shared network folder.  Say S:\MasterFrontEnd.   That master shortcut which already has an icon will need to be copied down to the users desktop with the target of the shortcut UPDATED to say :    C:\Users\<the.user>\OneDrive - Personal\DBFolder/PMD_FE.accdb.    I used to be able to point the target to H:\DBFolder, where H:  implied the username.   But this implementation by  this new IT made it  c:\john.smith\OneDrive - Personal\... which made the implementation more challenging.   But this will only happen once. Rather not personally go to each desk.

Comment: `ALL_USERS_DESKTOP` is the desktop under `C:\Users\Public` which maybe is not what you wanted.  That might explain the problems.  If you copy the shortcut from the network folder to the user's personal desktop it should work fine.

Comment: Yes.  I did try that and was hopeful.  But it still doesn’t recognize that the shortcut is there enough to latch on and modify the shortcut. You said you got it to work on your desktop. So are you able to change the target path to something else?  If we can get past that point, mission accomplished,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.  For some reason I could not get `ParseName` to work, but looping the desktop items and checking for the name was ok.

```vb
Sub Tester()
    ChangeShortcut "Test.lnk", "C:\Temp\Docs"
End Sub


Public Sub ChangeShortcut(strNameOfShortCut As Variant, strNewShortcutTarget As Variant)
    Const DESKTOP = &H10&
    Dim objShell As Object 'shell As Shell32.shell
    Dim objfolder As Object 'Shell32.folder
    Dim objfolderItem As Object 'Shell32.folderItem
    Dim objShortcut As Object 'Shell32.ShellLinkObject
    Dim objShellLink As Object, itm As Object, ok As Boolean
    
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objfolder = objShell.Namespace(DESKTOP)
    If Not objfolder Is Nothing Then
       For Each itm In objfolder.items
           If itm.Name = strNameOfShortCut Then
               ok = True
               Set objShortcut = itm.GetLink
               If Not objShortcut Is Nothing Then
                   objShortcut.Path = strNewShortcutTarget    'To Change
                   objShortcut.Save
                   ok = True
                   MsgBox "Shortcut changed"
               Else
                   MsgBox "Shortcut link within file not found"
               End If
           End If
       Next itm
       If Not ok Then MsgBox "Shortcut file not found"
    Else
       MsgBox "Desktop folder not found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou!  Mission accomplished.  Because of the loop, I was able to investigate the shortcut names that were on my desktop.   It didn't like the ".lnk" extension.   Once removed, VOILA - IT WORKS!